# Calling vectors in readcol from a string array?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I would like to generate vector names using and put them in a string array, and then I need to call these vector titles in with the readcol command. Here is basically what I want:

vectorname1/vectorname2 are string arrays with the desired names of each vector
spreadsheets is a string array of the file names of all of the spreadsheets I want to load in

For I = 0, n do begin

readcol, spreadsheets[I], vectorname1[I], vectorname2[I], format='x,d,x,x,d'

endfor

Plot, vectorname1_1, vectorname2_1

I have tried using the execute command (i.e. execute('readcol,' + spreadsheets[I] + ',' + vectorname1[I] + ',' ...) but IDL returns an error when it encounters the additional quotes in the format keyword.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It would help to clarify your question a bit by formatting code [using Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  Also, I think you've forgotten a word in your first sentence (using what?).

Comment: It seems like you're also missing some punctuation.  Could you try to clarify what the end result is supposed to be?  I'm a little confused as to what the larger problem is and I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your issues is using single quotes within single quotes.  Use the single quote mark twice in a row.  For example:

```
retval = execute('print, ''hi''')
```